# Compare Chinese unicode strings, when multiple code points are the same character?

Tags: unicode, normalization, cjk, unicode-normalization

I'm writing some Java code that deals with Chinese characters, and I got some unexpected results -- strings that should be equal were not.  Here is one of the offending characters, which means "six" (pinyin: liù): 六.  This character can be represented with either of two code points:

F9D1 in the block: [CJK Compatibility Ideographs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template%3aUnicode_chart_CJK_Compatibility_Ideographs)
516D in the block: [CJK Unified Ideographs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CJK_Unified_Ideographs,_part_1_of_4)

Wikipedia has a [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs) about these character ranges, and the short section on compatibility ideographs does mention some duplicates, but the list omits this specific character.

So I'm wondering:

1. Is there a list of duplicate unicode characters somewhere so I can transform Strings before trying to compare them?
2. Is this normal when dealing with CJK characters, or have I done something else wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just normalize them.  U+F9D1 becomes U+516D under any of the four normalization schemes:

```
$ export PERL_UNICODE=S

$ perl -le 'print "\x{F9D1}\x{516D}"' | uniquote -v
\N{CJK COMPATIBILITY IDEOGRAPH-F9D1}\N{CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-516D}

$ perl -le 'print "\x{F9D1}\x{516D}"' | nfd | uniquote -v
\N{CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-516D}\N{CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-516D}
$ perl -le 'print "\x{F9D1}\x{516D}"' | nfc | uniquote -v
\N{CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-516D}\N{CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-516D}
$ perl -le 'print "\x{F9D1}\x{516D}"' | nfkd | uniquote -v
\N{CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-516D}\N{CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-516D}
$ perl -le 'print "\x{F9D1}\x{516D}"' | nfkc | uniquote -v
\N{CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-516D}\N{CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-516D}
```

Many essential Unicode tools, including those, are available [here](http://training.perl.com/scripts/).

Comment: Thanks.  I found the Java equivalent in the class `java.text.Normalizer`.

Comment: @RobN Yes, exactly. Sorry I didn’t mention that; I had thought you would know where it was already. I was just trying to show that normalization takes care of it.